# Taking date as input in Python and passing it as an argument to oracle query to_date ()

Tags: python, oracle

I'm taking the date input as below:

```
year = int(input('Enter a year'))
month = int(input('Enter a month'))
day = int(input('Enter a day'))
date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
print date1
date1.strftime('%year-%month-%day')
print date1
```

Tried 2 ways and got the below output :

```
    query_cnt = "select  * from Table_name where CLOSED_DATE > 
    to_date(to_char(date1),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Enter a year2018
Enter a month8
Enter a day1
2018-08-01
2018-08-01
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./closed.py", line 41, in 
        cursor.execute(query)
    cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "DATE1": invalid identifier

```
query_cnt = "select  * from Table_name where CLOSED_DATE > to_date(:date1,'yyyy-mm-dd')
Enter a year2018
Enter a month8
Enter a day1
2018-08-01
2018-08-01
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./closed.py", line 41, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

Manual entry of date works fine
    query_cnt = "select  * from Table_name where CLOSED_DATE > to_date('2018-08-01','yyyy-mm-dd')

I want that date to be a user input value through python , kindly help

Comment: Maybe this article helps. Take a look at the "Using bind variables" section. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html